# How do I 'lift up' a setState function in a react component using hooks?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a component with shared state that needs to be in sync.

One piece of state sets the current musical scale type, which should support every possible scale, but I'm starting out with minor and major. The second piece of state sets the correct notes for the chosen note name, based upon the scale type chosen. I have it mostly working, but I need to synchronize the state better so that one can react to the other.

It has been recommended by a few people in the react community to 'lift the state up', which I am trying to figure out how to do properly, especially using hooks.

So, I have been able to figure out how to lift up the state of the musical scale notes that was being set on the components into some objects full of arrays, but now I need to figure out how to lift up the `onClick` function in the following code, and there are 12 of these note name components, and each one is setting different musical scales to the `notes` state:

```js
<NoteInput
  id="c"
  scale={scale}
  type="radio"
  name="notes"
  label="c"
  value="c"
  onClick={
    () => setNotes(
      scale === 'minor' ? scalePatterns['c-minor'] :
      scale === 'major' ? scalePatterns['c-major'] :
      ''
    )
  }
/>
<NoteLabel
  whileHover={{ scale: 1 }}
  whileTap={{ scale: 0.9 }}
  scale={scale}
  htmlFor="c"
>
  {
    scale === 'major' ? 'C' :
    scale === 'minor' ? 'C' :
    'C'
  }
</NoteLabel>
```

So now I need to figure out how to 'lift up' the arrow function in the onClick prop into it's own function, but I don't know how to go about it, as the requirement is that I need to pass different state to each instance of the function, but keep that state in sync with another piece of state, which is setting the scale type that the note buttons then react to.

UPDATE:

Upon closer inspection, I believe the state functions as follows:

```
Scale Type
  |     \
  |      \ 
  |    Root Note
  |      /
  |     /
Scale Notes
```

...where the scale type will affect both which root note is chosen (C# or Db, for example) as well as the notes for the scale itself. Then the scale notes ALSO need to know the root note in combination with the scale type.

Comment: `      onClick = () => {
         
      }
`
You can pass arrow function like this.

Answer (score 1):

Based on what I understood from your question, you have the following dependencies in your state -

```
Root Note       Scale
        \       /
         \     /
          Notes
```

The `notes` state variable only changes when there is either a change in `root note name (c/d/e etc)` or `scale (major/minor etc)`. You can abstract away all of the scale related state into a context and use it in the respective component as shown below. You can use the `useEffect` hook's 2nd arg to listen to state variable changes and perform [side-effects](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html).

**ScalesContext.js**

```js
...

const SCALE_PATTERNS = {
  "c-major": ["c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "a", "b"],
  "c-minor": ["c", "d", "eflat", "f", "g", "aflat", "bflat"]
};

const ScalesContext = createContext(null);

export const ScalesContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [rootNote, setRootNote] = useState(""); // 'c'
  const [scale, setScale] = useState(""); // 'major'
  const [notes, setNotes] = useState([]); // ['c', 'd', ...]

  // On scale/rootNote state change -> update notes
  useEffect(() => {
    const key = `${rootNote}-${scale}`;
    setNotes(SCALE_PATTERNS[key]);
  }, [scale, rootNote]);

  return (
    <ScalesContext.Provider
      value={{ rootNote, scale, notes, setScale, setRootNote }}
    >
      {children}
    </ScalesContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const useScalesContext = () => useContext(ScalesContext);
```

**App.js**

```js
...

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      // Hook up Provider around ScaleSelect component
      <ScalesContextProvider>
        <ScaleSelect />
      </ScalesContextProvider>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**ScaleSelect.js**

```js
...

export const ScaleSelect = () => {
  const state = useScalesContext();
  const { rootNote, scale, notes, setScale, setRootNote } = state;

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Root Note: {rootNote}</p>
      <p>Scale: {scale}</p>
      <input
        type="text"
        value={rootNote}
        placeholder="Root Note (try 'c')"
        onChange={e => setRootNote(e.target.value)}
      />
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Scale (try 'major')"
        value={scale}
        onChange={e => setScale(e.target.value)}
      />
      <p>Notes: {JSON.stringify(notes)}</p>
    </div>
  );
};
```

I have a working example here - https://codesandbox.io/s/scales-notes-d8o18?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: hmmmm...Dan Abramov suggested a simile thing on twitter and it mostly works except for one last issue...I think that my state is actually a bit more complex, as the scale will affect both the root note and the scale notes and the scale is affected by both. The reason for this is that sometimes the root note needs to change based on the scale type...for example, if the scale is major than one uses ‘Db’ but if the scale is minor then the correct root note is ‘C#’...so I’m thinking I need to lift up the root notes, but I still need them to change to set the scale notes...hope that makes sense...

Comment: Here is a link to a sandbox that dan made and forked...it's almost there, even without useEffect or context, except that the root is also dependent upon the scale type, so when a user selects `Db major` and then switches to `C# minor`, the notes don't automatically update, but rather the user must re-click the selected button to see the minor notes, which is not the intended effect...soooo close, tho!! XD......https://codesandbox.io/s/keez-beez-switchingalmost-2ikvs

Comment: I updated the question to reflect my new understanding of the state and it's interactions.

Comment: Glad that you are were to able to identify the state interactions covering your use-cases, I only wanted to convey that you should abstract all the state that is dependant on each other into a context and use side-effects in one place, also you need to be careful about cyclic dependency between your state variables.

Comment: hmmm..well, do you have any thoughts as to how i might be able to handle this more complex state relationship? Do you think I need to start looking into something like useReducer?

Comment: Yes, useReducer might be a better option in this case as you might want to extend the state to add more properties apart from the above 3 that you mentioned. It will also make the dependency relationship more clear in the code as you will be doing changes to multiple state variables based on the dispatched actions.